# Backbone collection and underscore functions implementetion

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbone (and to underscore as well). I am a little bit confused about the usage of pure underscore functions and their implementation in backbone.

For example, I need to sort a collection and then iterate over it.
If I would need to do only one of them, then this one works:

```
this.collection.each(function( item ) { .... }, this );
```

and this one also:

```
this.collection.sortBy(function(obj) { return obj.get('position'); })
```

But then, in order to combine them I couldn't figure out how (and if) I can chain them. The only way I could do it is:

```
_.each(this.collection.sortBy(function(obj) { 
    return obj.get('position'); 
}), function( item ) { .... }, this );
```

While I would like to do something like:

```
this.collection.sortBy( ... ).each( ... )
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly declare a chain of operations by calling `collection.chain` that proxies [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) on the collection. For example:

```
var ms = this.collection.chain();
ms.sortBy(function(m) {
    return m.get('position');
}).each(function(m) {
    console.log(m.get('position'));
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/t4JCm/1/

You can then get your ordered/modified/updated models via

```
 ms.value();
```